# Pulling two ints from string in C

Tags: c, string, parsing

Say if I have a string like this

```
char foo[10] = "%r1%r2";
```

I want to take out the `1` and `2` and convert them into `int`s. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: String "like" what?  %-letter-number-%-letter-number? just jumbled mix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (sscanf(foo, "%%r%d%%r%d", &i1, &i2) != 2)
    ...format error...
```

---

> When you do the format for `sscanf()` I understand `%d` is a decimal int but why do you have `%%r`?

If you're looking for a literal `%` in the source string, you use `%%` to specify that in the format string (and in `printf()`, you use `%%` in the format string to generate a `%` in the output); the `r` represents itself.

There are other ways to specify the conversion, such as `%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d`; that uses assignment suppression (the `*`) and a scanset (`[^0-9]`, anything that's not a digit).  This information should be obtainable from the manual page for `sscanf()`.

Comment: This helps thanks but I have a question...when you do the format for scanf I understand %d is a decimal int but why do you have %%r? I'm not exactly sure what that does could you explain?

Answer (score 2):

YOu can use `sscanf()` to get your result

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your string really has two '%' and one number after each of them.
for instance:

```
  char foo[10] = "%123%874";
```

don't forget to include stdlib library:

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
```

the following code will get 123 into r1 and 874 into r2.

```
  for(int i = 1; ; i++)
      if(foo[i] == '%')
      {
          r2 = atoi(&foo[i + 1]); // this line will transform what is after the second '%' into an integer and save it into r2
          foo[i] = 0; // this line will make the place where the second '%' was to be the end of the string now
          break;
      }
  r1 = atoi(&foo[1]); // this line transforms whatever is after the first character ('%') into an int and save it into r1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[MAXLEN];
int counter = 0; 
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(foo); i++){
   if(isdigit(foo[i]) && (counter < MAXLEN)){
        array[counter++] = (int)(foo[i]-'0');
   }
}
//integers are in array[].
```